# How to validate field only if it's value is entered in Laravel 4?

Tags: validation, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 in which I have field email or pincode you can say.
So while using Laravel validator I want to check if it is email or not only if it's value is filled else it will ignore it..

Answer (score 7):

You can use "sometimes" rule to your rule list:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, array(
    'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
));
```

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Answer (score 1):

You can simply have an `email` rule on the field.  If you do not have a `required` on the field then it won't fail if empty, but when it is entered, it must be an `email`.

That will satisfy your use case above.

So...

```
$validator = Validator::make(
array('pincode' => 'email'),
... other field => rules
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel will not know about the value before posting your data, So you have to use javascript to check the email syntax validation

Comment: I know about client side validation !I am talking about server side validation !